# How can I select a different column from each row?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table which has three columns with three records. How can I select first value of the first column, second value of the second column, third value of the third column?

```
table
============
test_tab

id1   id2   id2
===   ===   ====
100   400   700
200   500   800
300   600   900
```

Required output like :

```
100  500  900
```

How can I achieve this by using Oracle SQL or PL/SQL?

Comment: what would be the output if number of row is 4 for id2

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the "first" row in a table.

Comment: Please provide first, valid data. 2 columns with the same name in the same table is not Valid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a means of establishing what "first" means.
In Oracle, here is one way to address the example from your question:

```
create table test_tab(
  id1 integer,
  id2 integer,
  id3 integer
);

insert into test_tab values(100,400,700);
insert into test_tab values(200,500,800);
insert into test_tab values(300,600,900);

commit;

select sum(decode(pos, 1, id1, null)) id1,
       sum(decode(pos, 2, id2, null)) id2,
       sum(decode(pos, 3, id3, null)) id3
  from(
    -- this subquery produces a rank column for the whole dataset
    -- with an explicit order
    select id1, id2, id3, rank() over (order by id1, id2, id3) pos from TEST_TAB
  );
```

In this implementation, the subquery is used to establish an ordering of the rows, adding a new `pos` column based on the `rank()` function.

The `sum(decode(pos, 3, id3, null))` construct is an Oracle idiom for picking one specific row (row 3 in this case) while ignoring the others.
Basically, for your three rows, the `decode` will result in `NULL` for any row but the one with the specified number, so the expression for `id3` will only have a non-null value for the third row, hence the sum over the group will be equal to `id3` in row 3.

There are many ways to do it, this is just one, and you will likely need to make some adjustments to this implementation for it to work properly in your real code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, How you would identify which row is the first and which one is second?

Oracle does not guarantee the order of the records, it must be ordered using `order by` clause explicitly else it will be, we can say random order (The default query output)

With your test data and result, You can use the following query:
Note: I am considering the third column as ID3 and ordering the rows using ID1

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE RN
        WHEN 1   THEN ID1
    END) AS ID1,
    MAX(CASE RN
        WHEN 2   THEN ID2
    END) AS ID2,
    MAX(CASE RN
        WHEN 3   THEN ID3
    END) AS ID3
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ID1,
            ID2,
            ID3,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                ORDER BY
                    ID1
            ) RN
        FROM
            TEST_TAB
    );
```

Cheers!!